# get value from inputbox in php and refresh accorting to value

Tags: javascript, php

I want to refresh the page when the value is taken as an input. However, my code runs only once.
Where is my problem in the following code?

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['refresh-time'])){  
        $_SESSION['value'] = $_POST['refresh-time'];
        for( $i = 0 ; $i < $_SESSION['value'] ; $i++ ){
            $value = $_SESSION['value'];
            $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            header("Refresh: $value ; URL=$url");
        }

    }
?>
<form class="form-inline" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">referesh number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="refresh-time">
    </div>  
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-pencil" ></i> apply</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You haven't provided any javascript

Comment: So you want someone on here to write the code for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *onClick* property for the button element in this way:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onClick="window.location = 'the url you want to navigate'"> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Apply </button>
```